# Neglect Authorization header in some Axios requests of the app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I am setting my headers access token like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function setAccessToken(data) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `${data}`;
  axios.defaults.headers.common['content-type'] = 'application/json';
  axios.defaults.headers.common.accept = 'application/json';
}

export function removeAccessToken() {
  if (axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization) delete axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
}
```

I am using redux-saga, what I want to do is to avoid sending authorization in the header even when the user is logged-in in some requests of the app, is there's a way to achieve this?